# python 2.7 can't find a module in the Lib directory

Tags: python

I'm running some code that is trying to import this module but failing with the error code

```
 File "X:\python_2_7\lib\distutils\tests\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
   from test.test_support import run_unittest
 ImportError: No module named test_support
```

The test_support.py file is located in the directory:

```
 X:\python_2_7\Lib\test
```

Can anyone shed any light on what the problem might be?

Thanks,

EDIT: there is an **init**.py file in the lib directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"python -v" is your friend.  It should report where modules are sought and where they are found.

Comment: thanks really good tip. It was finding another directory in the path that wasn't the 'lib' directory do didn't contain the test_support module

Answer (score 2):

You should fix the path by adding a file like pathfix.py, the content is below

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test'))
```

And add an empty file `__init__.py` in your `lib` dir:

> $ cd lib
>   $ touch `__init__.py`

You need do `#import pathfix` at top of your every file that need import the module in lib.